# SQL join and where with ON (specific items) to get results in order

Tags: sql, mysql, join, where-clause, sql-order-by

sample code

```
SELECT b.title, i.barcode
 FROM biblio b
 JOIN items i 
    ON b.biblionumber= i.biblionumber
 Join biblioitems bi 
    ON i.biblionumber=bi.biblionumber
 where i.barcode IN (4088,6183,6191)
```

above SQL given results as below,

[image]

how do I get results in IN (4088,6183,6191) as entered order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below modified Query.

```
SELECT b.title, i.barcode
FROM biblio b
JOIN items i ON b.biblionumber = i.biblionumber
JOIN biblioitems bi ON i.biblionumber = bi.biblionumber
WHERE i.barcode IN (4088, 6183, 6191)
ORDER BY FIELD(i.barcode, 4088, 6183, 6191);
```

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ORDER BY` with `CASE` statement :

```
<You query>
order by case i.barcode 
          when 4088 then 1
          when 6183 then 2
          when 6191 then 3 
      end
```